# How many .snk files do I need?

Tags: .net, strongname

Say I have several .NET assemblies and want to sign each of them with a strong name. Is one keypair (one .snk file) enough or do I need to generate one pair for each assembly? Will I have to publish the public key of (each) keypair?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need only one .snk file.

You don't need to publish the public key.  Any one can get a public key using sn.exe with -p switch.

Comment: But how will he ensure that it was me who published the assembly?

Comment: The fact that it is signed with your key -- the same key the referencing assembly is expecting -- authenticates it to the assembly loader.

Comment: That only proves that is is signed with the same key as the one which comes with the assembly. But how can one identify who generated that key?

Comment: Asked a separate question for that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798621/do-i-need-to-publish-the-public-key-from-snk-file

Answer (score 1):

One key file is enough to sign multiple related assemblies.  Take a look through your GAC.  Assemblies from the same product or platform often all have the same key.  For example many of Microsoft's .NET framework assemblies share the same key.

Comment: Is one keypair enough for a whole company?

Answer (score 1):

We have (3) .snk files.

One that we use to sign our assemblies, one that was shipped for on-site code generation (we don't need to do that anymore), and mono.snk to sign Mono.Cecil and Mono.Security (these are built here for use with Microsoft's .NET).